# Confusion about nth root of a number

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, roots

Let's say we want to find the 6th roots of 64. Then according to the method from my textbook:

$z^6=64$

$z^6=64+0i=64[\cos(0)+i\sin(0)]=64cis(0)=64cis(0+2k\pi)$

Then by De Moivre's theorem:

$z=\color{red}{64^{\frac{1}{6}}}cis(\frac{2k\pi}{6})$  $,k=0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$

$z=\color{red}{2}cis(\frac{k\pi}{3})$

So that $z=cis(0), 2cis(\frac{\pi}{3}), 2cis(\frac{2\pi}{3}), 2cis(\frac{3\pi}{3}), 2cis(\frac{4\pi}{3}), 2cis(\frac{5\pi}{3})$

So the way I understand that is that we want to prove that the equation $z^6=64$ has six different solutions. In other words that there are six different values of $z$ that satisfy $z=64^{\frac{1}{6}}$. If so, then why do we simplify $64^{1/6}$ to just $2$ in the process, what about the other five values?

Comment: See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_value

Comment: Let I give you an analogy. The solutions of $x^2 = 4$ are $ x = 2$ and $x=-2$. The solution of $x = 4^{1/2} = \sqrt{4} = 2$. Where did the solution -2 go to?

Comment: $$\sqrt[3]{-8}=?$$

Comment: Any complex number $z$ that satisfies $z^6=64$ has to satisfy $|z|^6=|z^6|=64$, or $|z|=2$. The rest of the work is dealing with the arguments of these $z$. This you have done using the ${\rm cis}$-notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The is because $\;64^\frac16\;$ is the *modulus* of a sixth root, i.e. it is  the sixth root as a *positive real* number, not as a complex number.

Answer (score 0):

Notice:

$$z^6=64\Longleftrightarrow z^6=|64|e^{\arg(64)i}\Longleftrightarrow z^6=64e^{0i}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=\left(64e^{2\pi ki}\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}\Longleftrightarrow z=2e^{\frac{\pi ki}{3}}$$

With $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $k:0-5$

So, the solutions are:

$$z_0=2e^{\frac{\pi\cdot0i}{3}}=2$$
$$z_1=2e^{\frac{\pi\cdot1i}{3}}=2e^{\frac{\pi i}{3}}$$
$$z_2=2e^{\frac{\pi\cdot2i}{3}}=2e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$$
$$z_3=2e^{\frac{\pi\cdot3i}{3}}=-2$$
$$z_4=2e^{\frac{\pi\cdot4i}{3}}=2e^{-\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$$
$$z_5=2e^{\frac{\pi\cdot5i}{3}}=2e^{-\frac{\pi i}{3}}$$